# sudo gem install rmagick Not working

Tags: rmagick

I am installing  rmagick,Its giving me error of

Found partial installation at: /usr
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later.

Although  I have installed the ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 ,Location is  /usr/local/bin/identify,

I don't understand the what is the reason behind this.Please help me...

Comment: Please some body help me......

Answer (score 0):

I was just bitten by the same thing on Ubuntu 10.04.  The fix was to install libmagick9-dev, not libmagick-dev (without the 9)